# Angularjs2 'templateUrl' in @Component - how to display razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-services, angular2-directives

How to render a ASP.NET MVC5 Razor View (.cshtml) in the 'templateUrl' in @Component. On using '/Home/Index', the page hangs.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Product } from './model';
import { InventoryService } from './dataService';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `<ul>
        <li *ngFor="let product of products">
            <h4>{{product.getProducts()}}</h4>
        </li>
    </ul>`,
    //templateUrl: '/Home/Index',
    providers: [InventoryService]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    products: Product[];

    constructor(private productService: InventoryService) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.productService.getAll()
            .then(products => this.products = products);
    }
}
```

Server Side Routing (RouteConfig.cs):

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Angular's main page is the MVC's shared _Layout.cshtml file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->

    <script src="~/node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="~/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="~/Scripts/systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.import('../Scripts/main').catch(function (err)
        {
            console.error(err);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
```

The web api controller (ProductController.cs) is accessible directly and procuces valid JSON output.

```
[Route("api/Product/GetProducts")]
        public IEnumerable<ProductJSON> GetProducts()
        {
            IQueryable<ProductJSON> products = _context.Products.Select(
                    p => new ProductJSON
                    {
                        Name = p.Name,
                        Category = p.Category,
                        Price = p.Price
                    });
            return products.ToList();
        }
```

HomeController.cs is as below:-

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }
    }
```

Index.cshtml is as below:-

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<my-app>Loading...</my-app>
```

I am able to access '/Home/Index' path successfully when using 'template', but application hangs and not able to access on using 'templateUrl'

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `<ul>
        <li *ngFor="let product of products">
            <h4>{{product.getProducts()}}</h4>
        </li>
    </ul>`,
    //templateUrl: '/Home/Index',
    providers: [InventoryService]
})
```

Comment: are you using webpack or SystemJs?

Comment: I am using SystemJS

Comment: How does your Server side routing looks like? Is Angular main html page different than your Controllers path? Are you able to access Web controller directly?

Comment: @Madhu Ranjan : Added the details asked above by you in the question above.

Comment: you did not add how your HomeController and Index.cshtml looks like and are you able to access /Home/Index path?

Comment: @Madhu Ranjan : Added further details as asked for in the original question above.

Comment: where you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need a little different approach when mixing ASP.NET MVC5 and Angular, you need to separate your Root component path and ASP.NET default path.

Try below,

Create a new Controller let's say **ComponentsController** like below,

```
public class ComponentsController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Components
        public ActionResult App()
        {
            return View();
        }
 }
```

and add a `Components\App.cshtml`, make sure no shared _Layout is used.

```
     <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let product of products">
            <h4>{{product.getProducts()}}</h4>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

update `AppComponent` template URL, so that it uses new path,

```
templateUrl: '/Components/App'
```

Remove shared Layout for your Index.cshtml as well and get it served directly from Index.cshtml, fix path based on your project structure

It should work.

Check this [Github Repo](https://github.com/ranjanmadhu/Angular2-101/tree/master/Angular2InASPMVC) with a basic application.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Adding App.cshtml doesn't work. Loaded libraries, polyfills, SystemJs in head section. Code for body part of App.cshtml is as :              
`</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <my-app>
            <ul>
                <li *ngFor="let product of products">
                    <h4>{{product.getProducts()}}</h4>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </my-app>
</div>
</body>
</html>` Had to modify 'RouteConfig.cs' to render 'ComponentController' & App.cshtml. It doesn't work & Visual Studio hangs as before with my original approach with shared layout file.

Comment: @Bobby, Added a github repo in answer, check it, although it does not use ASP  Bundling and minification, but has a very basic angular 2 application with ASP MVC, Cheers!!